# Sequence of random selection with no two consecutive objects same

Tags: java, algorithm, random, random-seed

I wanted to write a function which can be subsequently called with a integer parameter (starting from 1 to 100) which randomly gives me an integer 0, 1, or 2 but never two same in a row.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class UniqueRandomObjectSelector {

    //Goal is to select objects from a bucket randomly with teh condition that 
    //no two selections in a row would be same
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "th random Object is " + selectObject(i) + " ");
        }
    }

    //Pick the object from the pool of 3 . e.g. the bucket contains the numbers 1, 2 and 3
    private static int PickObject(int j) {
        Random rand = new Random(getSeed());
        //Find i-1 wala number
        for (int i = 1; i < j; i++) {
            rand.nextInt(3);
        }
        return rand.nextInt(3);
    }

    //Fixed seed so that random number generation sequence is same
    static long getSeed() {
        return 11231;
    }

    static int selectObject(int index) {
        //Holds the sequence of Objects
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int prev = -999;
        int i = 1;
        //Keep generating the sequence till we have the requested index of objects 
        while (list.size() <= index) {
            //Get a random number from fixed seed
            int ranNum = PickObject(i);
            //Check if this was same as previous 
            while (prev == ranNum) {
                ranNum = PickObject(++i);
            }
            prev = ranNum;
            list.add(ranNum);
            i++;
        }
        return (list.get(index));
    }
}
```

Can this be simplified , looks like I am using too many loops.

Comment: There's a quick simple algorithm: generate a sequence of binary digits.  Add one to each.  Compute the cumulative sum of them modulo 3.  This shouldn't take more than one or two lines of code, depending on taste, and by avoiding tests and eliminations, it's likely to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're seeding the RNG and pulling the entire sequence every time you want a number. You don't need to do that. Instead, give `rand` a wider scope. That way you can reuse it each time you want to get a number.

This makes things simpler because you don't need to iterate over the list each time, so you don't have to build the list *at all*. That means you no longer have to loop in `pickNumber()`, and most of what you have in `selectObject()` is obsolete also.

Not only is this *simpler*, but it's also *faster*. Instead of looping/generating the whole list each time, you only have to grab a couple numbers until you have a good one. On average, this will be `4/3` tries per call, since about a third will be duplicates.

Try something like this instead:

```
public class UniqueRandomObjectSelector {
    int seed = 11231;
    int prev = -1;
    int range = 3;
    Random rand;
    int[] values;
    int maxIndex = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       /// to generate value 37 on the fly
       System.out.println("37th value is " + selectObject(37));

        /// to print 1000 in order (and store them in an array)
        rand = new Random(seed);
        list = new int[maxIndex+1]; 
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
            values[i] = getRandomNonRepeating();
            System.out.println(i + "th random value is " + values[i]);
        }

       /// to get value 37 from values[]
       System.out.println("37th value is " + values[37]);
    }

    static int selectObject(int index){
        rand = new Random(seed);
        int value = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<=index; i++)
            value = getRandomNonRepeating();
        return value;
    }

    static int getRandomNonRepeating() {
        int next = -1;
        while(next == prev || next < 0){
            next = rand.nextInt(range);
        }
        prev = next;
        return next;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed clean however the only reason I have to re-generate the whole sequence everytime because I need a master function which just takes the sequence number and gives me the random number associated with it.

My Ultimate goal is to call selectObject(int index) as part of webservice which takes the index as query parameter. My program will not have a main function like above to generate all the numbers at same go.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, you can still do that more efficiently. Basically your `selectObject(index)` will just loop exactly like the `main()` does above, but return the last one instead of printing them all. Let me update the code sample.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know `index` will not go above a certain value, you could just precompute them(up to max) into an array and persistently store it. Then it's as simple as retrieving one number each time.

Comment: The problem with the Alternative solution you suggested is that this Function is at an endpoint of massive webservice where I am allowed to do as many computation as I want but strictly no persistence or caching.

Comment: In the new code of yours we are storing the variable prev globally , can we bring it inside any method ?

Comment: Well I fixed it by storing rand and prev inside the method itself.